# CImg reading image exception

Tags: c++, image, cimg

I am using CImg to read a .png file, like following:

```
// DGT.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "..\CImg\CImg.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cimg_library;

long ReadImage(char *fileName)
{
    CImg<unsigned char> image(fileName); // stackover flow exceptions thrown here.

    return 0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ReadImage("D:\\Projects\\DGT\\DGT\\shepplogan256.png");
    return 0;
}
```

However, the stack overflown exceptions is thrown at `CImg<unsigned char> image(fileName);` when trying to load the image. The image is there, so I am wondering where I messed up and how to read the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) or [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) to load PNG-Files with `CImg`.

Comment: I also tried another .jpeg file, it throws same exception?

Comment: OK. I guess you are right. I tried to load a .bmp, and there is no problem with that. I guess it means some libraries are missing. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah... I was a little disappointed since I thought CImg can handle different image types.

Comment: CImg is not for loading images, its mainly for manipulating them. :)

Comment: OK, so who is good at loading different images in c++ then, any chance you can educate me?

Comment: Still `imagemagick`, if you want many formats. Just `libpng` or `libjpg` for specific. I dunno, your decision. Choose what you want

Answer (score 0):

To read .jpeg or .png files natively, CImg needs you to link your code with either libpng or libjpeg, and that you define macros `cimg_use_png` or `cimg_use_jpeg`.
By doing so, ImageMagick is not required at all. I prefer this solution as it does not require installing a new (external) software to read image files, and eases the distribution of the binaries as well.